# Getting special div class data while parsing html in swift with Kanna

Tags: html, swift, parsing, xpath

Google image search returns result links like this:

```
<div class="rg_meta notranslate">{"cb":6,"cl":21,"cr":9,"ct":6,"id":"G9X757bOKIt_dM:","isu":"hitparade.ch","itg":0,"ity":"jpg","oh":300,"ou":"http://streamd.hitparade.ch/cdimages/jennifer_rush-i_come_undone_s.jpg","ow":296,"pt":"Jennifer Rush - I Come Undone - hitparade.ch","rid":"xArn9C5TiVuF9M","rmt":0,"rt":0,"ru":"http://hitparade.ch/song/Jennifer-Rush/I-Come-Undone-1581","s":"Jennifer Rush - I Come Undone","sc":1,"st":"Hitparade.ch","th":226,"tu":"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q\u003dtbn:ANd9GcRbLwVl711N3Q93C-SFdj1a1X6CLQIohPbb_8G9eBEJBX_bzQdC","tw":223}</div>
```

How can I correctly get the image path (in the "ou" field) in this div

```
rg_meta
```

with Swift and Kanna?
I have tried several variants, e.g.

```
// Alamofire.request...
if let doc = Kanna.HTML(html: html, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
    for item in doc.xpath("//div[@class='rg_meta']") {
        print(item.text)
        print(item["ou"])
    }
}
```

but the item is always empty. Is this Json data in the div? Is there a way to get the "ou" field with Kanna?
Thanks.

---

Edit:
An example for generating the html to test the xpath expression would be:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=jennifer+rush+i+come+undone&gbv=2&tbm=isch
```

---

Edit2:

ok, while Adrians answer seems to capture correctly the json data in the field "ou", my code is still not working as intended, I did some more debugging:

As I see now, my main problem seems to be that the div class I intend to capture is not downloaded by Alamofire. It seems the reason for this is that this is not in the html body google returns, but far below in a struct I don't understand. One could see it in the source code of the search result.

My test code so far:

```
    let requestUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q=jennifer+rush+i+come+undone&gbv=2&tbm=isch"
    Alamofire.request(requestUrl).responseString { response in
        print("Request success/charcount: \(response.result.isSuccess) \(response.result.value?.characters.count ?? 0)")
        if let responseHtml = response.result.value {
            if let doc = Kanna.HTML(html: responseHtml, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                for item in doc.xpath("//div[@class='rg_meta']") {
                    print(item.text ?? "---")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Request success/charcount: true 40830
```

40k html are downloaded, but the entire source code viewed in browser is about 600k. Is there any way to download everything so that I can do the search for the special div class ?
I tried

```
Alamofire.request(requestUrl).responseData
```

and

```
Alamofire.download(requestUrl, to: destination)
```

also, but all return the 40k html.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you not need to include 'notranslate' in your xpath expression (i.e. `for item in doc.xpath("//div[@class='rg_meta notranslate']")`? Just ran your expression through an online xpath tester and got no results

Comment: Adding 'notranslate' does not make a difference, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let yourText = "<div class=\"rg_meta notranslate\">{\"cb\":6,\"cl\":21,\"cr\":9,\"ct\":6,\"id\":\"G9X757bOKIt_dM:\",\"isu\":\"hitparade.ch\",\"itg\":0,\"ity\":\"jpg\",\"oh\":300,\"ou\":\"http://streamd.hitparade.ch/cdimages/jennifer_rush-i_come_undone_s.jpg\",\"ow\":296,\"pt\":\"Jennifer Rush - I Come Undone - hitparade.ch\",\"rid\":\"xArn9C5TiVuF9M\",\"rmt\":0,\"rt\":0,\"ru\":\"http://hitparade.ch/song/Jennifer-Rush/I-Come-Undone-1581\",\"s\":\"Jennifer Rush - I Come Undone\",\"sc\":1,\"st\":\"Hitparade.ch\",\"th\":226,\"tu\":\"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q\\u003dtbn:ANd9GcRbLwVl711N3Q93C-SFdj1a1X6CLQIohPbb_8G9eBEJBX_bzQdC\",\"tw\":223}</div>"

// You can use some other method to extract the text from the div 
let rawJson = yourText
    .components(separatedBy: "<div class=\"rg_meta notranslate\">").last!
    .components(separatedBy: "</div>").first!


guard let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: rawJson.data(using: .utf8)!, options: []),
    let json = jsonObject as? [AnyHashable : Any]
else {
    return
}

print(json["ou"])
```

Comment: thanks. The code does not compile like this, I have to change: jsonObject(with: (item.text?.data(using: .utf8)!)!  Anyway, it still does not work, the print(item.text) is always nil, so the json serialization has nothing to work with I guess. Seems that the xpath expression does not find the right div class...

Comment: did some debugging - the line print(item.text) is never reached. So doc.xpath() is empty, without any items. The xpath expression does not find the div/class section at all...

Comment: I have added text "Edit2" to my question. If someone could point out a solution how to download the *entire* data from the example website so that the special div class can be parsed, that would be great, Thanks

Comment: Google works with javascript, and it make asynchronous request. I can't help you to parse google site because google have api for this

Comment: ok, I understand that now. I see the original question for parsing the special div class as answered, although my task is still not solved (because as I see now I don't get to download the code with this special class from google with Alamofire in the first place, probably because of scripting on client side). Will mark the question as answered. Thanks